# Weird empty space when printing a google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the process of rebuilding a custom team eligibility checker for the local little league I volunteer for, and while it still has a long ways to go I'm trying to get printing working.

The code is still quite sloppy I will admit but everything shows up properly, on screen that is.  When I actually go to file->print a weird horizontal white space appears roughly a quarter of the way down the map as shown here http://rowast.com/bootstrap/template/map-2.php?type=roster.

To replicate the error simply click the "Lakewood Village 9-10 All Stars" and then click the print icon.

I've investigated my own code as well as google's map markup and nothing pops up to indicate why this error is occurring, especially as to why it only occurs when being printed.

The error occurs differently depending on what browser you are in, and the code doesn't work at all yet in IE.

Thanks in advance if anyone knows whats up.

Answer (score 0):

Its a CSS issue.

Tough I completely didn't understand your css but these classes- `.container.map-whole #map.map-map` and `.win-firefox .container.map-whole #map.map-map, .mac-firefox .container.map-whole #map.map-map`

have a  `height: 1119px !important;` specified.

This height value is being inherited while you open the print page to your map because of which, the actual map only remains in the `649px` of height that you gave and remaining `470px` is shown as an empty space.

Comment: Maybe firefox didn't fire the map resize event but this [link](http://cl.ly/image/1L2j1p2t1u29) is how it appears in chrome (on mac) when going to print.

The code has got messy and bogged down as I push towards getting things to print right...

Comment: I tried putting 100% height for the parent div of the map including body and html, the space is still coming. I did similar to this post to print the google map. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050215/google-maps-api-v3-printing-maps.  Can you please tell how I can get rid of the empty space in the print preview of the map..