# Open New Window and Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, printing, fancybox-2

I would like to use a print button like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print() window.open()">Print</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onClick:"window.print() window.open()">Print</a>
```

Both doesn´t work at the same time.

All `iframes` an `Fancybox 2` contens should open in new window an at the same time by clicking on this button and a print-dialog should started.

Thanks for your help.
Ongi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox - add print function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485198/fancybox-add-print-function)

Comment: even though the question was closed, the answer seem have worked for many people. You may just need to tweak the API options and selectors and update them to v2.x

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onClick:"window.open(); window.print();">Print</a>
```

This should open up the new window and the print window at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
<a href="prin_page_url.php" data-original-title="Print registration form" data-toggle="tooltip" target="_blank" onclick="if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('opera') != -1 &amp;&amp; window.event.preventDefault) window.event.preventDefault();this.newWindow = window.open('prin_page_url.php&amp;url='+escape(document.location.href.replace('http://','').replace('https://',''))+'&amp;referrer='+escape(document.referrer.replace('http://','').replace('https://','')), 'mibew', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,status=1,menubar=0,width=640,height=480,resizable=0');this.newWindow.focus();this.newWindow.opener=window;return false;">Print</a>
```

And write print js code on **body** of prin_page_url.php as below:

```
<body onload="window.print()"> or window.onload = function() { window.print(); }
```

There is url is `prin_page_url.php` and it's used two time. it will be open on new window with new url without any menu items of browser.

Comment: Just now i have tested its working fine, then why giving -1