# Printing with Fancybox2 and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox-2

I have searched and tried to get this working, but I cannot figure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to print from fancybox using the @media print from css.  To this point I have not been able to get the button or even a link to appear on the screen.  Here is my code...

CSS

```
@media print
{
body * { visibility: hidden; }
#fancybox-content * { visibility: visible; }
#fancybox-content {position:fixed; top: 5px; left: 5px; }
}

#print-link {
position: absolute;
top: -12px;
left: -15px;
height: 32px;
width: 85px;
background: url("../images/drawings/fancybox/print.png") top left no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 1103;
}
```

HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
      $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function(){link = '<a id="print-link" href="javascript:window.print()"></a>';$('#fancybox-close').before(link);}                
    }); 
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox - add print function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485198/fancybox-add-print-function)

Comment: I was trying to make it work with the @media print since it didn't pull up the separate html page before printing.  Using the code in the listed link (which I had working before), I can make the image print, but if I pull up a gallery of images only the first image will print.  If the user scrolls to another photo they cannot print any longer. Not even the original.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: see my **Edit #2** at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11485923/1055987 for a working solution of fancybox v2 image gallery.

Comment: After further review, I found that the attr("rel","gallery") setting was causing a problem with my galleries when I had multiple galleries on the same page grouping them with the rel attribute.  It also caused problems with the click function for duplicate thumbnail images where I only wanted a single gallery image. I remove the attr("rel","gallery") from the function definition and the printing still worked fine.  I'm thinking that is because I'm defining the "rel" value in my image links. Is there a reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: using `rel` in your links is perfectly fine to separate your galleries. `.attr("rel","gallery")` is the lazy way to ask jQuery to do it for you if you don't want to do it manually as you did.